# Random Transform in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, transforms

**Q:** How can i randomly rotate several separated faces, wich are part of the same object, in z-axis in edit mode?

**Context:**
I have ≈150k instances, some are rivets and some are screws, i need to random vary z +/-0.5mm each rivet, and random rotate z each screw.
I must avoid making instances real since doing so renders the scene unstable, hard to edit and nearly impossible to render.
I managed to do the z variation for the rivets using a displace modifier with clouds texture but could not manage to achieve the random per face/screw z rotation.

Comment: What do you mean per faces?  If the screw itself count as an object one by one, using **random proportional transform** with **local orientation** and pivot point set to **individual** should handle this very well.

Comment: Hi @HikariTW, i mean per instancer face. To do as you suggest i'd need to make instances real. To work more efficiently i need to keep them as instances.
If in edit mode i select all instancer's faces, and rotate them in Z-Axis pivoting in their individual origins, the effect is they all rotate the same, i need that rotation to be random.

Comment: Those faces is disconnect and separated? Then use **Normal Orientation**, all step should be similar. In the 3D View panel > Toolbar > Mesh > Transformation > Randomize

Comment: Yes, they are all separated, i've tried before but the effect of that randomize function can not be limited to one axis or to one function, it just grabs the vertices and randomly moves them in random directions. I wonder if they can be rotated given their world space location somehow.. i'll google that..

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that in edit mode Randomize Transform is not able to use